# How to return html with php variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, return, html-select

I want to return cats value  in select options and cats id as option id.I am successfully returning cats values as follows.

```
if($nu) {

                $cat_name = array();

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sq2)) {
                    $cat_name[] = $row['cat_name'];
                }
                return $cat_name;

            }
```

But I want to return both cats values and their ids in option tag.I tried this but failed .Please help

```
if($nu) {

                $cat_name = array();
                $cat_id = array();

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sq2)) {
                    $cat_name[] = $row['cat_name'];
                    $cat_id[] = $row['id'];
                }
                  return "<option id='$cat_id'>$cat_name</option>";

            }
```

Comment: Your variables are arrays, so you need an index. Do you want to return just one cat or all of them?

Comment: @HanletEscaño I am using  while loop,That means i needed all the related rows

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
$html = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sq2)) {
    $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
    $cat_id = $row['id'];

    $html .= "<option id='".$cat_id."'>".$cat_name."</option>";
}
return $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something more like this, need to add each line as you go

```
if($nu) {


$option = "";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sq2)) {
   $option.= <option id="$row['id']">$row['cat_name']</option>
}
 return $option;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return 1 option by cat ?

Your need to concat your HTML in the loop.

```
if($nu) {

            $html = "";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($sq2)) {
                $html .= "<option id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['cat_name']."</option>"
            }
            return $html;

        }
```